# Getting error when import openai to python

Tags: python, openai-api

I installed openai using this command:

```
pip install openai
```

When I `import openai` I'm getting this kind of error.

How do I fix this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openai
  File "/home/nadun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openai/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from openai.api_resources import *  # noqa
  File "/home/nadun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openai/api_resources/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openai.api_resources.completion import Completion
  File "/home/nadun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openai/api_resources/completion.py", line 14
    def create(cls, *args, timeout=None, **kwargs):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Which python version are you using? Try printing version on terminal/command prompt. In your error, it seems `/home/nadun/.local/lib/python2.7`. Do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: I'm worked with `ubuntu 18.04` with `python2.7`. After that, I was updated to `python3.9` . Then try to install `openai`, but now I'm getting this kind of error.  `Collecting pandas==1.2.3 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.2.3 ` do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue but was due to the version of python.

After upgrading to python3.10 the issue was solved

Comment: Does openai support python2.7? I'm trying to use their whisper speech-to-text api.

Comment: I don't think so, answered here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75736162/cannot-import-openai-in-python-2-7-18

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have installed openai at the python 2.7 and it needs python 3.

Step by step guide if you need help on that:

Check your environment version:
`python -V`

The output should be something like:
`Python 2.7.*`

What worked for me was uninstalling the openai at Python 2.7:
`pip uninstall openai`

Installing python 3 and making sure the environment is set to it, you can [manage that with pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/). Once you have pyenv installed and a version 3 installed (at this day, my version is 3.11.3), you should be able to run those commands:

`pyenv versions`

It should output a version 3.*. If it does not appear, check the "manage that with pyenv" link again.

Set your environment version to 3 (in my case, 3.11.3):
`pyenv global 3.11.3`

Check your environment is set to 3.* :
`python -V`

The output should be something like:
`Python 3.*`

Then install openai cli:
`pip install --upgrade openai`