# Cannot import openai in python 2.7.18

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, importerror, openai-api

I recently started a project which involves some modules from python 2.7 . In this I wanted to integrate also the openai module but when I tried to import it (after installing it with `pip install openai`) this error accured:

```
>>> import openai
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openai\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from openai.api_resources import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openai.api_resources.branch import Branch
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\branch.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openai.api_resources.abstract.engine_api_resource import EngineAPIResource
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 46
    **params,
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to install an older version of openai (0.6.0) but this error still pops up. Unfortunatly due to some other modules, which are fundamental in my project, I cannot upgrade python past the 2.7 version. Is there some way I can solve this issue without having to upgrade python?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code it looks like even older versions of this package do not support python 2.7, even though "Python 2.7+" is listed as an option in the requirements section of the readme and on PyPI. The comma at the end of the kwargs (`**params`) is a syntax error in versions of python older than 3.6.

Comment: Is there something I can do or am I forced not to use this package?

Comment: Short of using a supported version of python (e.g., 3.7+), I don't think so

Comment: as a super hacky but viable workaround you could incorporate python 3 in your mainly python 2 project by [spawning a subprocess](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/subprocess.html) at runtime when you need to use the openai api, calling a python 3 script that interfaces with the api. Then after the python 3 script writes the output to a file, read that file in your python 2 program

Comment: ^which is obviously bad practice, but it qualifies as something you can do

Comment: @Noah Hi, I'm trying something similar to what you've mentioned here but there's something I'm stuck with in trying to implement it. Would you like to address my query, I've raised a question regarding the same, if you could guide me on it It'll be amazing.